# Flutter TextField selection highlighter controls appear too high

Tags: flutter, textfield, texteditingcontroller

Screenshot of the issue and code in use below, the selection controls are above the textfield for some bizarre reason.

[image: Example of issue]

```
var textField = TextField(
  selectionHeightStyle: BoxHeightStyle.max,
  scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 20 * 4),
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true, decimal: true),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
  ),
  controller: textEditingController,
  onTap: () {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 800), () {
      textEditingController.selectAll();
    });
  },
  onSubmitted: (newText) {
    if (newText.length == 0) {
      callback(0, true);
    } else {
      callback(int.parse(newText), true);
    }
  },
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4!.copyWith(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
        fontSize: 16.0,
        color: WWColors.pinkBrandColor(),
      ),
);

return Padding(
  padding: padding,
  child: Container(alignment: Alignment.center, child: textField),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to my own question, this in the TextField attributes did the job in my case:

```
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    isDense: true, // important line
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 5),
    border: InputBorder.none,
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try create a custom widget for it to make the customisation as you required below is the simple example for the mentioned implementation.

```
class CounterWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final double spaceWidth;
  final Color controlColor;
  final Color valueColor;
  final Function(int count) callback;
  const CounterWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.callback,
    required this.controlColor,
    required this.valueColor,
    this.width = 50,
    this.height = 30,
    this.spaceWidth = 5,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<CounterWidget> createState() => _CounterWidgetState();
}

class _CounterWidgetState extends State<CounterWidget> {
  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          //Incrementor
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                count++;
                //Callback method to expose the count to the higher hier archy.
                widget.callback(count);
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: widget.controlColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(widget.height / 0.1),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(widget.height / 0.1),
                ),
              ),
              child: const Center(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              width: widget.width,
              height: widget.height,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: widget.spaceWidth),
          Container(
            color: widget.valueColor,
            width: widget.width,
            height: widget.height,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                count.toString(),
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: widget.spaceWidth),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              if (count > 0) {
                setState(() {
                  count--;
                  widget.callback(count);
                });
              }
            },
            child: Container(
              width: widget.width,
              height: widget.height,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: widget.controlColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(widget.height / 0.1),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(widget.height / 0.1),
                ),
              ),
              child: const Center(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.remove,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```